# Push To Docker Hub from Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a **bitbucket-pipelines.yml** file with the code below

```
image: atlassian/default-image:2

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name:
            Build And Publish To Azure
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            #Authenticate on Azure
            - docker login -u $AZURE_USER -p $AZURE_PASS myticket.azurecr.io
            #Build Docker Image
            - docker build -t myticket.azurecr.io/myticket .
            #Push to Azure
            - docker push myticket.azurecr.io/myticket
      - step:
          name: 
            Push To Docker Hub
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - docker logout
            #Authenticate on Docker
            #The below says Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device
            - docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password-stdin $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD
            #The below says invalid username or password
            # - echo $DOCKER_HUB_PASSWORD | docker login --username $DOCKER_HUB_USERNAME --password-stdin
            #Build Docker Image
            - docker build -t myticket.azurecr.io/myticket .
            #Push to Docker Hub
            - docker push isaachats/myticket:latest
```

I have added comments with the errors I am getting, What am I missing? I also tried adding hub.docker.com to the login line in step two but still failed. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either

```
docker login --username "$DOCKERHUB_USERNAME" --password "$DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD"
```

or

```
echo "$DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD" | docker login --username "$DOCKERHUB_USERNAME" --password-stdin
```

should work just fine.

If you are seeing "invalid username or password" error messages, check those credentials again, they are most probably wrong. Rotating the token you are using should cut it.

Comment: Turns out the Username on Docker Hub in the browser is not case-sensitive and when I use `--password` I am getting an error message that says I should use `--password-stdin`

Comment: Isn't it more of a warning/advise? In a CI system where there is no shell history and logs mask secrets you can "safely" ignore it